# constrain inner div with text-overflow: ellipsis (or similar) without max-width

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flexbox row with multiple cells and the last cell (D4, lets say) will be of variying width (`flex-grow: 1`). This div will contain inside it, another div that has the actual text. Now, my problem is that the text is going far beyond the width of the parent div (D4). I tried adding `text-overflow: ellipsis;` and `overflow: hidden`, but without a fixed `width`, it naturally isn't working. What's the best way to tame this inner div please?

Here's a little mockup of what I'm trying to do - and in this snippet, I've constrained the parent div `.menu` to 500px, but, that's just for demonstration and my actual div is the width of the page. When the text is longer than the parent width, it extends beyond the page and adds scrollbars to the page, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

How can I achieve this please?

```css
/* converted from scss */
.menu {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 500px;
}

.menu__item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

.menu__item--description {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.menu__item--description div {
  display: flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%; /* doesn't work */
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu__item">One</div>
  <div class="menu__item">Two</div>
  <div class="menu__item">Three</div>
  <div class="menu__item menu__item--description">
    <div>
      But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to add `min-width: 0` to `.menu__item--description` (min-width for flex items gets calculated as "content-based minimum size" by default), and you need to _remove_ `display: flex` from the inner div. ([`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow#formal_definition) "applies to: block container elements")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `overflow: hidden;` to `.menu__item--description` and remove `display: flex;` on the `.menu__item--description div`.

```css
/* converted from scss */
.menu {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 500px;
}

.menu__item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

.menu__item--description {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu__item--description div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu__item">One</div>
  <div class="menu__item">Two</div>
  <div class="menu__item">Three</div>
  <div class="menu__item menu__item--description">
    <div id="tekstdiv">
      But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have only changed a little. Added an `overflow: hidden;` and removed a `display: flex;`:

```css
/* converted from scss */
.menu {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.menu__item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

.menu__item--description {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu__item--description div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu__item">One</div>
  <div class="menu__item">Two</div>
  <div class="menu__item">Three</div>
  <div class="menu__item menu__item--description">
    <div>
      But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```